# ssis to get google analytics data

Tags: ssis, google-analytics-api

My company is using a SSIS component called SSIS [googleAnalyticsSource](http://analyticssource.codeplex.com/) to get company website traffic data from Google analytics.

This has been working fine until this morning, the component can't log in to Google analytics. The google account used can log in GA in browser no problem though. So I guess there must be something changed in GA API, which caused the component to fail. Since this is a free component, we don't expect to receive support on this. I am thinking of writing c# script in script component to get the data. I haven't done any GA api so would like someone point me to the right direction. Thanks.

Basically I want to get some dimensions (date, medium, source) and related facts (visitors, visits, etc).

Comment: That application isn't going to work anymore it uses client login client login was shut down on April 20 2015.   There is a SSIS data reader for Google Analytics http://www.targit.com/en/resources/store/ssis/data-reader-for-google-analytics which uses Oauth2 and works.   Note: I am a developer on that product.

Comment: Thanks. will have a look.

Comment: For those who run into similar issue, we have found a solution, which is to use SQL Server 2012 version of SSIS and use the same component for SQL Server 2012. That will work the reason I guess it uses a different authentication method. BTW, my question is in SSIS 2008. I will give a try to Dalm's solution when I got sometime.

Comment: That task works from SSIS 2005 - 2012.  Check it when you have time.  I am glad you got your system working.

Comment: It's been a  a long time, but I just tried the component by DalmTo and it's working and great! More than that, the installation is super easy. Is this free? Because I didn't see the pricing etc.

Comment: Hey, one question, when I try just two dimensions with one metrics (country, date with users), the result is correct, however, when I try more dimensions, the result (users ) changes more or less. It seems the result is not stable.

Comment: Check that you data isn't being sampled

Comment: I think I figured it out why, when added many dimensions (7 in my case), the users metric will be listed for all these dimensions, then if doing a sum will include duplications (users for dimension a can be the same users for dimension b). When doing that sort of query in GA portal, it takes of that so that will be correct. What I do now is take just date dimension and users metric then use the date to join with other metrics. So your component is correct. Thanks.

Comment: @DaImTo great component! Is it free?

Comment: yes its free to download the SSIS task and connection manager itself.  The integration of the TARGIT BIA suit is not free.